# How do you use "or" in function logic in Google Sheets to tell Sheets when to count and not?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Ok so I have been trying all I can think of and Googling up a storm over here with no luck. I am trying to write a function in Google Sheets that will look at a range which includes two different columns. The function should go to row 3 and look at column 1 and then 2 then row 4 and so on and so forth. I want the function to look at both columns and if either of them is not blank then I want it to count that up. As it stands right now I have tried sum and countif and countifs and adding two different countifs. This leads to double counting. I only want a row counted once as long as at least one of the columns is NOT blank. I know how I would do it in a code editor but not with built-in spreadsheet functions as none of them seem to touch on my specific case and I don't think "or" is being used the way I would expect. Any suggestions or thoughts would be appreciated.

[The "3" on the right should be a "2" since the first row has two dates in its columns and the second row has one date in its columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAnvV.png)

[Just the current formula I have tried that is double counting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rv8kN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(SUM(IF(AB3:AB<>"", 1, )))
```

or perhaps:

```
=INDEX(SUM(IF((AB3:AB<>"")+(AC3:AC<>""), 1, )))
```

where + sign acts as OR logic

Comment: the second option did the trick! Thanks so much not even close to the stuff I was trying. I would never have ended up here thanks again